# Is there any method like getColumnClass in JTable to set row specific data types?

Tags: jtable

I have a JTable with two columns: a key name and the value. In the value columns are multiple data types allowed like this image:

[image: On the left are the keys and on the right the values (a simple "Map")]

So in column 1 I might have a boolean in row 1 and a string in row 2. But the method `getColumnClass(...)` only allows me to set a data type for the complete column.

Is there any way to set column-row specific data types?

Greetings,
mythbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two data types to the same column. But for your case, my suggestion is use rendering.

1. Read about [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).
2. Define the column data type as a component class which contains a `JPanel`.
3. Render the column. Your Renderer class returns a Panel to the column. It should have a `constraint`, basing on that you should add components to the Panel and return the Panel.

This example shows how rendering can be used in these kind of cases.

```
class PanelCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
       // row number is used as a constraint.
        if(row == 0) {
            this.add( new JTextField("", 20));
        } else if(row == 1) {
            this.add( new JCheckBox());
        } else if(row == 2) {
            this.add( new JButton());
        } else {
            this.add( new JLabel("Row-4"));
        }
        return this;
   }
}
```

// Output:

The first row is a panel with `JTextField`.
Similarly 2nd, 3rd rows has `JCheckBox` and `JButton`.
4th row has a `JLabel` with text.

[image: Panel Containing Diff Components]

**P.S:** This is just a try. Even I haven't done this before. Please correct me if I am wrong.